# I cannot display data to a dialog textView when I previously select a spinner SQLite value in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-spinner, android-dialog

I have a spinner with a value coming from a sqlite database

I select the value in the spinner and I get the id of the value

I open a custom dialog and I want, based on the previous id to find the values in my SQLite and set the text of some TextViews with these values

```
if(selected_id!=null)
   {
       Cursor MyCursor = mHelper.getSelectedSeason(selected_id);
       txtPickName.setText(MyCursor.getString(MyCursor.getColumnIndex("name")));
       txtPickStart.setText(MyCursor.getString(MyCursor.getColumnIndex("start")));
       txtPickEnd.setText(MyCursor.getString(MyCursor.getColumnIndex("end")));
      }
```

But

I get a magnificent

```
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
```

My query is the following:

```
public Cursor getSelectedSeason(int id)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery("select * from seasons where season_id=" + id + "", null);
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try move cursor at last position, mycursor.MovetoLast